# Estimating SWR based on multiples of resonant length

Tags: impedance-matching, antenna-tuner

I am planning to buy a Xiegu G90. It has an internal tuner that can tune up to SWR 5:1. Does anyone know if I have a resonant antenna on 40m, what I will have for a SWR on 80m?

Comment: Depends on the type of antenna, small loop, dipole, trap vertical, etc.

Comment: Is your "resonant antenna" a center-fed dipole?

Comment: No it is a MFJ 5m telescope antenna on my car roof resonant at 20m and then a bottom coil attached to make it resonant  at 40m. so wondering it I can tune it to 80m with the G90..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very high. Harmonics work the other way around — antennas can be useful on *higher* bands than the design band, but almost never *lower* bands. A dipole cut for 40m might be good on 15m. An end-fed or a loop for 40m might be good on 20m and 10m. But pretty much any design of 40m antenna is going to be a *half-size antenna* on 80m, and very unlikely to be tunable with any builtin ATU.